# Printing Web page that uses ng-repeat

Tags: angularjs, printing, angularjs-directive

I'm debating whether to use the ng-repeat directive from Angular on my website. I want to use it on a table of items however I know customers print this page off. My question is will the page still print off correctly if I use ng-repeat to make a table rather than writing out the entire table in HTML? Or should I stick to the HTML?

The flexibility and interactivity that ng-repeat would provide really makes me want to use it but if it doesn't print out how it's displayed on screen then I can't use it

Answer (score 2):

of course it will, ng-repeat just generates normal HTML.

Answer (score 0):

Yes it will.

ng-repeat is a `directive` that angularJS *compiles* at run-time and turns into plain old **HTML**.